# RewriteRule not working when sending more than one value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo

I'm trying to SEO friendly the following url:

.../profiles.php?Country=string-of-country&Page=7 (Page can be any integer)
to:
.../profiles/string_of_country/7

For instance if no page number is given it should also redirec, e.g.

.../profiles.php?Country=string-of-country
to:
.../profiles/string-of-country

and even if there is no string with a specific country, it should redirect, e.g.

.../profiles.php
to:
.../profiles

My .htaccess looks so far like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
# Remove slash to urls
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule  ^profiles$                 /profiles.php?Country=world&Page=1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^profiles/(.+)?$           /profiles.php?Country=$1&Page=1    [L]
RewriteRule  ^profiles/(.+)/([0-9]+)$   /profiles.php?Country=$1&Page=$2    [L]
```

Everything seems to work, except for the last RewriteRule - where I request for a country string ($1) and any integer ($2).

I've tried several options, but all without success. Can somebody please tell me how to set the htaccess rules correctly when requesting more than one value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to either change your ordering or make the 2nd to last rule less "greedy", as the `(.+)` pattern is gobbling up all parameters.

Either reverse the order of the last 2 rules:

```
RewriteRule  ^profiles/(.+)/([0-9]+)$   /profiles.php?Country=$1&Page=$2    [L]
RewriteRule  ^profiles/(.+)?$           /profiles.php?Country=$1&Page=1    [L]
```

Or make the pattern less greedy:

```
RewriteRule  ^profiles/([^/]+)?$           /profiles.php?Country=$1&Page=1    [L]
```

Comment: I chose the less greedy rule... at the end I could wrote all 3 Rules in one...  RewriteRule  ^profiles/?([^/]+)?/?([0-9]+)?$  /profiles.php?Country=$1&Page=$2  [L]   On the php I have programmed if country is empty or invalid country then show "world"... thanks!